# NullPointerException in Generic List

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, generic-list

I've been scouring the 1000's of NullPointerException posts on stackoverflow and cannot for the life of me figure why this is happening; aside from the obvious (that it is null). Can someone help me understand what it is that I am not understanding about Generic Singly LinkedList that is causing me to get this run time error.

Here is my code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

public class GList<T> {         
    private GNode<T> head;
    private GNode<T> cursor;

    private static class GNode<E>{
    private E data;        //NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION
    private GNode<E> next;

    public GNode(E data, GNode<E> next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}                
public static class InnerList<E> {
    private String name;
    private GList<Integer> inner = new GList<Integer>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public GList<Integer> getInner() {
        return inner;
    }
    public void setInner(GList<Integer> inner) {
        this.inner = inner;
    }
}
public boolean hasNext(T cursor) {
    /*
     * returns whether or not the node pointed to by 'cursor' is
     * followed by another node. If 'head' IS null, returns False
     */
    if (cursor != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public void insertFirst(T t) {
    /*
     * puts a new node containing t as a new first element of the list
     * and makes cursor point to this node
     */     
    if (hasNext(t) == false){
        head = new GNode<T>(t, head);
        head.next.data = t;
        cursor.next = head;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("List is not null.");
    }
} 
public static void main(String[] args){

GList<InnerList> list = new GList<InnerList>();

String ln = "hello";
list.cursor.next.data.setName(ln);  //NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION

/*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 *at GList$GNode.access$0(GList.java:10)
 *at GList.main(GList.java:67) 
 */
}
}
```

This is homework, so an explanation would be most helpful as I am sure I will be dealing with LinkedList throughout the coming months.

Comment: It's good to post the exception stacktrace also.

Comment: He's got it at the bottom.

Comment: NPEs can be thrown in any context. First of all you should try to understand what the general causes can be (take a look the JavaDocs).

Comment: wow, that's a whole lot of dots on line 67 of main.  The NullPointerException is telling you that *one* of those references before a dot was null.  If you're capable of running your program in a debug mode IDE it's by far the easiest to set a breakpoint on that line and see what's null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using the default constructor, for which you haven't given an implementation

```
GList<InnerList> list = new GList<InnerList>();
```

None of its fields are being initialized and so

```
list.cursor == null
```

Java stops execution here, but your other fields are also null. Take the time to revisit your code and initialize all the relevant fields.

The fact is you shouldn't try to access anything in your list since you haven't added any items to it. Its `head` and `cursor` are null.

Comment: Do I initialize it in the main method?

Comment: No. Since the fields are private you won't have access to them from outside that class. What you want to do is provide a default constructor for your `GList` class and do all your field initialization there.

Comment: Thank you! I'll play around with this some more.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by doing this: GList<String> list = new GList<String>(); ...the problem is that the assignment calls for GList<InnerList> list; I don't understand how to make that work if it won't initialize the list properly or it says 'not applicable to for * arguments?

Comment: Ask another question. You'll get more support than commenting here.

Answer (score 1):

On this line `list.cursor.next.data.setName(ln);` you are attempting to reference properties of objects that were never initialized.

Where you declare cursor, next, and data you set no value.  In your main method you never set the value of head or cursor, so they are still null. Then you attempt to reference them and get a NPE.